# JSON Schema to match any type

Tags: json

How can I create a JSON Schema to match ANY object basically, a schema like:

`{"type": "anything"}` so it can match:

```
{ "testing": "123"}

{"testing" : {"testingSub": "456"}}
```

How can this work? Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).